# use struts2.3.34 to redirect can't find the jsp

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

[image]

[image]

[image]

i use struts2.3.34 version ,i want to redirect to hello.jsp and hello.jsp under the WEB-INF,it's show 404,why can't visit hello.jsp
and i also try to write like this`<result name="testRedirect" type="redirect">/WEB-INF/hello.jsp</result>` ,also 404.
who can help me ?plz.

Comment: did you check that your war/ear includes jsp file?

Comment: @yılmaz yes，it under the WEB-INF,and I use type=redirectAction can visit it,but I use type=redirect directly to visit hello.jsp is 404

Comment: You cannot go to a JSP page directly when it's in WEB-INF. Your URL bar indicates you're not going to the action, rather the JSP. That's not how it works.

Comment: @DaveNewton yes,you are right,I move the hello.jsp out of the WEB-INF,and I can visit it.but I still have a problem,I know can’t directly visit the jsp in WEB-INF,so it’s mean that redirect to the jsp like directing to visits the jsp ?

Comment: I don't understand the question. You shouldn't be accessing JSP pages directly at all. In fact if there are S2 tags on the page they'll break anyway.

Comment: @DaveNewton I want to know that I redirect to a jsp view isn’t mean I directly to visit the jsp view by url,so I can’t to visit the jsp in the web-inf

Comment: A redirect is just that: a redirect. The browser requests the resource indicated in the redirect. Since you cannot access a JSP under WEB-INF the redirect fails. You can use `redirectAction` and hit an action that shows the JSP, but you can not access WEB-INF resources directly, and almost never access any JSPs *not* under WEB-INF directly anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Have a check on struts offical page.

```
<result name="success" type="redirect">
  <param name="location">foo.jsp</param>
  <param name="parse">false</param>
</result>
```

http://struts.apache.org/core-developers/redirect-result.html

Comment: I just tied it and it also doesn’t work,the error also is 404 ,can’t find the hello.jsp